# How @InboundChannelAdapter differs from MessageChannel when sending messages in Spring Cloud Stream 2.0

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I tried two methods to send message in Spring Cloud Stream 2.0 RC3.

One uses `MessageChannel` to send message.

```
public interface Chan {
    @Output
    MessageChannel sender();
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Chan.class)
public class TestApplication {
    @Autowired
    private Chan chan;

    public void sendMessage {
        chan.sender().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(obj).build());
    }
}
```

The other use `InboundChannelAdapter`

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel="sender")
public MessageSource<Object> sendMessage() {
    return () ->
            new GenericMessage<>(obj);
}
```

When sending java objects as payload, the two methods behave differently. The first method (using `MessageChannel`) enables consumers to receive java objects, for example,

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + obj);
}
```

prints out attributes of obj.

While the second method (using `InboundChannelAdapter`) let consumers receive an empty object (fails to convert a json string into pojo objects?)

I guess the difference may come from MessageConverters, but needs clarification.

Thanks.

Comment: Would be great if you share some simple project to reproduce the issue. Not clear though how one can do like you show `chan.sender().send(obj);`. The `send()` accepts only `Message<?>` type.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. Will edit the post.

Comment: Good, but still unclear how it can be a difference in the approaches since the channel is the same. That’s why I’m asking about the app to play from our side and reproduce

Comment: Please check this example: https://github.com/ccshih/spring-cloud-stream-samples/commit/99d6d0c008057885755d3521a9af06dd932b0035. If I pass object instead of string, this test will fail due to `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: Channel to receive a message whose payload is <org.springframework.cloud.stream.testing.source.Foo@97>
     but: received: "{\"x\":\"x\"}"`